# RCA RMS voltage

Tags: voltage, audio, rms

Searching the RCA phono input spec online does not garner any official documentation, probably due to the large number of voltage levels and power levels being used in commercial products. Looking at the Wikipedia page on [line level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level), a graph is provided with peak voltages of consumer and pro equipment.[image: Line level for consumer and pro equipment]

However, searching RCA RMS voltage online reveals a lot of discrepancies, with some people saying its peak is around .5V while other sources state different voltages of 775mV(0dBV) RMS and many other differing voltages.

What is the actual RMS value of an RCA output, and what does -10dBV imply?

Comment: There is no actual value. Your device outputs what it outputs and it may be set by you to some level by choosing a volume or depending what material you play. Let's see if there is a similar question already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 dBm is 1mW, to convert into voltage you need to know the impedance, which in this case is "600 ohms phone line", so 0dBm in audio context is 0.775 V RMS. In a RF context you'd use 50 or 75 ohms so the voltage would not be the same.

dBu and dBv are the same. 0dBm = 0dBv = 0dBu = 0.775V RMS.

0dbV (with a capital V) = 1V RMS.

> what does -10dBV imply?

\$ 1V . 10 ^{-10/20} = 0.316V RMS \$

(if the V was capitalized, otherwise replace 1V with 0.775V)

> What is the actual RMS value of an RCA output

Throw a dice and divide by 3 for RMS.

Signal to noise ratio is directly proportional to amplitude, likewise for noise immunity on the way between boxes, so high quality gear tends to have high output levels in order to score better on SNR benchmarks.

This means if you have an older amp which was designed for oldskool line levels (-10dBV) and you use it with a modern source, which will probably output 2V RMS or more, you will only get to use a tiny fraction of the volume pot, mostly at the left.

Comment: so if the output is from a decade-old TV, does that mean its RCA out RMS voltage will be at -10dBV(.316Vrms)? is there documentation on this, or is the RMS voltage just chosen by the manufacturer?

Comment: Maybe it's in the specs, if you can get them, otherwise... throw a dice! If your analog system runs on 5V or 3V3 and has to accept "line" input without clipping... you have to count on some sources outputting 2V RMS (+/-3V peaks)...

Comment: @lemon The output depends on what material you play. The TV gets the played signal somewhere and there is no guarantees what are the peak or RMS voltage levels of the material played so there is no one number you can know or calculate.